# What is the appropriate egg substitute for different types of vegan bakes?

Tags: veganism, egg-substitutes

When baking, I often end up working with egg substitutes based on what I have on hand at the moment. I know a few egg substitute tricks including applesauce, flaxseed, chia seeds, or store-bought substitutes such as Vegg and Just Egg (pea protein-based), but the results are inconsistent. I want to better understand when I should use which substitute depending on the type of bake (i.e., cakes, cookies, brownies, quickbreads, etc.)

What are the appropriate vegan egg substitutes for different types of bakes? When is applesauce better than a flaxseed "egg" or vice versa? Is there a better substitute when the goal of the egg is emulsification vs structure vs leavening (or a combination)?

Comment: Not an answer, but I've heard bananas often make a good substitute too

Comment: ah yes, @Wouter! that is another good one!

Comment: @Wouter surely that is an answer...

Comment: @Zanna it is an option to use as a substitute for eggs in certain instances, but the question was asking for the reasoning behind the substitute for each situation. I do appreciate the idea, though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this guide from [Kelly Roenicke on the pretty bee](https://theprettybee.com/guide-to-egg-replacers/).

Baking powder: pancakes

Baking soda and vinegar (or citrus juice): cakes and cupcakes

Ground flax seed: denser recipes like cookies or muffins

Chia seeds: denser recipes like cookies or muffins (she notes that if using black chia seeds, they will be visible in the final product)

Yogurt: cakes, cupcakes, and muffins (adds moisture)

Applesauce or other pureed fruit: works well across all recipes

Aquafaba: baking, mayonnaise, meringue